# Why is internet lost when I connect to Citrix?

Tags: vpn, rdp, citrix

I work on a server with a valid IP address. When I connect to a **Citrix VPN** server with **Citrix** receiver, I lose connection to the server and **Citrix** doesn't allow me to RDP to the server.

This issue happened when I upgrade the Citrix receiver to the latest version.

How can I get back the RDP connection to server or how to config **Citrix** to allow real IP connection?

Comment: you use terms like "*valid* IP address" and "*real* IP connection". What do you mean by them? Also, you seem to use the word "server" to refer both to either a vpn server, and an other server you use. Could you clarify, which is which?

Comment: valid ip equals real ip. I connect to server on internet with real ip and in server connect to a vpn server.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. All IP addresses you connect to are real.

Answer (score 0):

The one who can answer your question is the one running the Citrix VPN server.
Usually theres a policy to cut off all internet acceess for the connected vpn-client. Otherwise an attacker on the internet could use the connected vpn client as relay to access the tunnel.